# How do I check if item exist in database?

Tags: python, sql

```
name_search = request.form.get("name_search") #I will get an input from a form
name = db.execute("SELECT name FROM birthdays") #get the list of names in db
```

how do i check if name_search exist in name?

Comment: Open sql tutorial and look for **WHERE**

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```py
if db.execute("SELECT 1 FROM birthdays WHERE name = ?", [name_search]).fetchone() is not None:
    pass
    # record exists
else:
    pass
    # record doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execute(f"SELECT name FROM birthdays WHERE name = {name_search}")
```

This should give you no result if there is no record..